# Create a new connection in QGIS 3.4.3 DB Manager

Tags: postgis, postgresql, qgis-3, spatial-database

I am trying to establish a new database connection from QGIS 3.4.3 to Postgres/PostGIS. I have two connections established but I can't find any options to establish another connection. I cannot recall how the other connections were established and I can't find any information on how to do this.

Comment: If you right-click the PostGIS node (with the elephant icon) there is a 'New Connection' option that will allow you to add as many postgis connections as you want... I have 4 right now...

Comment: That makes a lot of sense @DPSSpatial but my right click returns no action. Maybe I need to uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: Oh that's weird - what operating system are you running?

Comment: Same experience for me in 3.10. I have to add connections via the "Layer"->"Data Source Manager" (click 'New' button, add new database connection) before they show up in DB Manager. Only Geopackage & Spatialite honor the right-click in my case.

Comment: @DPSSpatial, I'm on Windows 10

Comment: In the layer menu, use the datasource manager to add more connections

Comment: @DPSSpatial is talking about the QGIS Browser panel. Casivio, be sure that you are not checking in DB Manager. BTW, 3.4.3 is very old, and a lot of bugs fix happened since. Better to update to 3.4.15 !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the layer menu, use the datasource manager to add more connections:

[image]